# ClearCase delete view private files only

Tags: clearcase

Is there any was to delete only view private files in CC dynamic view. There are a bunch of eclipsed files and view private files in my view. I need to delete only view private files and retain checked-out and eclipsed files.

I tried following -

```
cleartool ls -r | grep -v eclipsed | grep -v checkedout | xargs rm -v
```

But looks like eclipsed files are listed twice with `cleartool ls`. So it deletes eclipsed files too :(

cleartool ls -r produces two outputs for an `eclipsed` file in dynamic view.

```
src.mk
src.mk@@ [eclipsed]
```

So deleting with `cleartool ls -rec | grep -v "Rule:" | grep -v "eclipsed" | grep -v "-->"  | xargs rm -v` deletes eclipsed files too.

Comment: What is wrong with `cleartool lsprivate`?

Comment: @mouviciel it should work also. I have added it to the answer.

Comment: @mouviciel "cleartool lsprivate" lists eclipsed files too.

Answer (score 3):

You are right, none of those two soution would work:

```
 cleartool ls -rec | grep -v "Rule:" | grep -v "eclipsed" | grep -v "-->"  | xargs rm -v
```

cleartool lsprivate | grep -v "eclipsed" | xargs rm -v

Source: my old answer at "[Command to find all view private files in the current directory recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7657120/6309)".

An `lsprivate` alone lists eclipsed file like any other private file:

```
M:\yourDynView\yourVob\aDir\>ct lsprivate

M:\yourDynView\yourVob\aDir\aFile.vsd
M:\yourDynView\yourVob\aDir\aPrivateFile
```

But, an `lsprivate -l` list eclipsed file twice:

```
M:\yourDynView\YourVob>ct lsprivate -long

view private object    M:\yourDynView\yourVob\aDir\aFile.vsd
file element           M:\yourDynView\yourVob\aDir\aFile.vsd@@ [eclipsed]
view private object    M:\yourDynView\yourVob\aDir\aPrivateFile
```

So you need three passes

- one to generate that `cleartool lsprivate -l`
- one to remove any line *above* a line which contains `eclipsed`
- one to read that file and delete the remaining private files listed in that file

The second step could be (loosely tested after [this thread](http://computer-programming-forum.com/11-awk/a9312d13f49f1fb8.htm))

```
gawk "{if ((NR!=1)&&($0!~/eclipsed/)) {if ($lastlin!~/eclipsed/) {print astlin};lastlin=$0} } END{print lastlin} " s
```

With '`s`' the file containing the result of a `cleartool lsprivate -l`.

Comment: "cleartool ls -rec | grep -v "Rule:" | grep -v "eclipsed" | grep -v "-->"  | xargs rm -v" is not working. I have updated the explanation above.

Comment: @LOK and the `cleartool lsprivate | grep -v "eclipsed" | xargs rm -v` I mentioned as an alternative in the answer? Would that work better?