# How to list all the files that are not VOB elements

Tags: svn, clearcase

I am moving from clearcase-lite (CC-LT) to SVN.

I need to list all the files of specific snapshot that are NOT elements so I can ignore them in my initial import to SVN.

Can you suggest on a shell or clear-case CLI to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`cleartool ls`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_ls.htm) is the main command here, for snapshot view (as opposed to lsprivate for dynamic views)

```
cleartool ls -view_only -r
```

But that list too many elements.

See "[Command to find all view private files in the current directory recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7657120/6309)"

For Windows:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in (`cleartool ls  -rec ^| find /V "Rule:" ^| find /V "hijacked" ^| find /V "eclipsed" ^| find /V "-->"`) do @echo "%%A"
```

For Unix:

```
cleartool ls -rec | grep -v "Rule:" | grep -v "hijacked" | grep -v "eclipsed" | grep -v -- "-->"
```

similar ideas are in:

- "[Command to find all view private files in the current directory recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/q/369697/6309)"
- "[ClearCase delete view private files only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15811695/6309)"
- "[How do I determine what files in my ClearCase local view have not yet been added to source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/191964/6309)"

Comment: Thanks @VonC, works perfectly. I used the last command you suggested above (UNIX) with some extra exceptions of my own.

Answer (score 1):

I also have symbolic links as elements As I wrote in [how to keep includes in svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24674708/how-to-keep-includes-in-svn) that I want to keep also in the repository.

I had to add those separately using the following command:

```
> cleartool ls -rec | grep "\-->"
```

while non elements do not keep the -->:

```
> ct ls Include/not_element.h
Include/not_element.h
> ct ls Include/element.h 
Include/element.h --> ../NetworkInterface/element.h
```

Comment: Good feedback. +1. It builds on my answer.